# GetExecutingAssembly().GetType to open form in class library

Tags: c#, winforms

Searched around and just can't to find a solution to this.
Using Reflection, I have opened many forms in the same namespace:

```
 Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(nameSpace + "." + formName);
```

Now, I'm trying to open a form in a separate class library and the type is always coming back null.

For instance, this always works:

```
 Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("ToolBox" + "." + "localSearch");
```

But if I try to open a form in a class library, it fails.

```
 Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("CodeConverter.Forms" + "." + "CodeConverter");
```

Here's the form from the class library:

```
 namespace CodeConverter.Forms
 {
     public partial class CodeConverter : Form
     { 
         public CodeConverter()
         {
         }
     }
 }
```

And to see the entire method:

```
    public Form GetFormByName(string nameSpace, string formName)
    {
        object oForm = new object();
        Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(nameSpace + "." + formName);

        //Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        //Type type = assembly.GetType(formName);

        Form frm = null;
        if (type != null)
        {
            oForm = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            frm = (Form)oForm;                
        }

        return frm;
    }
```

Just can't seem to find out why it won't work for a form in another assembly.

EDIT:

Did a small test and the namespace and form is not even listed:

```
        string test = "";
        foreach (Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
           test += t.FullName + ", ";
        }
```

EDIT 2:
Found the solution:

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(nameSpace);
        Type t = assembly.GetType(nameSpace + "." + formName);
```

Comment: You are using GetExecutingAssembly(), the odds that this is the class library are very small.  Well, zero, considering the outcome.  You'll have to know more about the assembly that the type lives in.

Comment: Because you're writing Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(). If form is inside in another assembly then...it's not in the currently _executed_ one. Note that if assembly is currently executing or mscorlib then you can directly go with Type.GetType(). For the others...specify a full type name. BTW if you own all the assemblies you may consider to use MEF